# how to display the second line of a file and translate the characters into uppercase

Tags: linux, shell

```
/home/msabbar/sample_dir2
`-- sample_dir
    |-- admin
    |-- cambridge
    |   |-- cafeteria
    |   |-- library
    |   `-- security
    |       |-- annex
    |       |-- building
    |       `-- parking
    |-- faculty
    |-- history.exe
    |-- markham
    |   |-- annex
    |   |-- building1
    |   `-- parking
    `-- stenton
        |-- gen_ed
        |   |-- Holidays
        |   `-- cars2
        |-- lib_arts
        |   |-- english.txt
        |   `-- match.doc
        `-- phone_directory
```

11 directories, 12 files

Your current directory is sample_dir. Display the 2nd line of the file cars2,
translated to uppercase (hint: start with a 'head' command):

okay so i did

```
head -2 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]" < stenton/gen_ed/cars2
```

and

```
head -n 2 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]" < stenton/gen_ed/cars2
```

but it's wrong

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do:

```
 head -2 your_file | tail -1 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
```

Answer (score 1):

can I ignore the hint (from your assignment I guess)?

```
awk 'NR==2 {print toupper($0);exit}' stenton/gen_ed/cars2
```

or

```
sed -n 'n;s/.*/\U&/p;q' stenton/gen_ed/cars2
```